# Python, BeautifulSoup iterating through files issue

Tags: python, loops, csv, beautifulsoup

This may end up being a really novice question, because i'm a novice, but here goes.

i have a set of .html pages obtained using wget. i want to iterate through them and extract certain info, putting it in a .csv file.

using the code below, all the names print when my program runs, but only the info from the next to last page (i.e., page 29.html here) prints to the .csv file. i'm trying this with only a handful of files at first, there are about 1,200 that i'd like to get into this format.

the files are based on those here: https://www.cfis.state.nm.us/media/ReportLobbyist.aspx?id=25&el=2014 where page numbers are the id

thanks for any help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv


for i in xrange(22, 30):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen('file:{}.html'.format(i))
    except:
        continue
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        n = soup.find(id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkBCLobbyist')
        name = n.string
        print name

        table = soup.find('table', 'reportTbl')
        #get the rows
        list_of_rows = []
        for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
            col = row.findAll('td')
            filing = col[0].string
            status = col[1].string
            cont = col[2].string
            exp = col[3].string
            record = (name, filing, status, cont, exp)
            list_of_rows.append(record)

        #write to file
        writer = csv.writer(open('lob.csv', 'wb'))
        writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append each time not overwrite, use `a`, `open('lob.csv', 'wb')` is overwriting each time through your outer loop:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('lob.csv', 'ab'))
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

You could also declare `list_of_rows = []` outside the for loops and  write to the file once at the very end.

If you are wanting page 30 also you need to loop in `range(22,31)`.

Comment: excellent!! so helpful! (tho now we have another little problem, but that i think i can deal with!)

Comment: no worries, the fact you saw the second to last page makes me think you want page 30 also so add one more to your range as above.

Comment: yes, thanks! had figured that one out - but now realizing the numbers in col[2] and col[3] aren't coming in unless they're $0.00; and there's a unicode error about 427 records in... but thanks for this! i may try to do the list of rows outside the loops to see if that works...

Comment: you may need to encode to utf-8 before you write to the file